# Optimize image pieces into multiple palettes

Tags: c#, colors

Does anyone know how to group a large number of images into a select number of groups by similarity of colours, so all images for each group can then be reduced to use the same (16-colour) palette?

See, I've been messing around with N64 graphics (specifically, the Command & Conquer ROM), and have encountered a peculiar storage mechanism for its terrain graphics; a series of (4-bit) images that reference a small amount of external 16-colour palettes.

Each piece of terrain is divided into 24x24 pixel 'tiles', and each of those can pick one of a select (less than 16) number of palettes. However, the original data never bothers optimizing this, and uses the same 16-colour palette for all tiles inside a single terrain piece.

Since the original PC game has 256-colour images, I want to write an optimizer for it and try to reconvert all the terrain. Basically this boils down to taking all the 24x24 tiles of all pieces of terrain (thousands of tiles, all together), dividing them into a limited amount of groups with similar colours, and then generating an optimal 16-colour palette for each group. So, it's a bit more complex than just generating a single palette for the whole bunch.

I have helper functions for a lot of indexed image operations (copy & paste, match colours to palette, stuff like that), and writing the actual colour reduction part will probably not be much of a problem either; there's plenty of code around for that here on Stack Overflow. It's just the initial colour analysis part that has me stumped.

Note that I do not need an actual image similarity algorithm. I've seen a couple of those. This is specifically and only about the *colours* used on the images, and how much they are used on the images.

[edit]

With some research I figured out that the best way to approach this was with something called "K-means clustering".

A friend who's pretty deep into into colour and image stuff advised me to make the actual algorithm a K-clustering method where the thing to approach for all members of a cluster would be "closeness to the generated 16-colour palette of the current cluster". This can be quantified into one value by taking the sum of the euclidean distances of each of the image's colours to their closest palette match (though with images with more than 16 distinct colours I'll probably have to work with averages there, since multiple colours will match one palette match). So I'm going to try that approach.

Funnily enough, the generating method *for* that generated palette will most likely be a K-means function itself...

Comment: Hm. The task sounds interesting but I wonder: If the original game was in 256 colors in 16 color tiles with 16 palattes - whre would the extra colors come from you could display if you actually had them??? Or did I get you wrong? Any chance to play with the tilesets?

Comment: The original PC version of the game has normal 256 colour graphics, without any oddities involved. On the N64 ROM they 'optimized' them to 16 colours per cell in a pretty bad way. The N64 _environment_ perfectly supports hi-colour, though. The 16 colour thing is purely to make the textures take less space on the ROM. 4-bit graphics = 2 pixels per byte, you see.